# Expand collapse icons change bootstrap CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make the expand collapse icons. My problem is when I load the browser first time, the icon is facing up and first click is facing up too. After that it looks good. I want to make the icon face down when I load the browser the first time and flip the icons every click.

jsfiddle.net/7zvxa/28/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `collapsed` class to your `arrow-toggle`:

```
<span class="arrow-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseH" id="collapseP">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/5vf6qd7q/

You need to update the css and add 'collapsed' class near to 'arrow-toggle' class.

HTML

```
<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <span class="arrow-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseH" id="collapseP"><span class="icon-arrow-down"></span><span class="icon-arrow-up"></span></span>
        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </h3>  

    <div id="collapseH" class="collapse">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="ic_tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#paragraph1" data-toggle="tab">Paragraph 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paragraph2" data-toggle="tab">Paragraph 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paragraph3" data-toggle="tab">Paragraph 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="ic_tabsContent" class="tab-content">


 <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="paragraph1">
            content 1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="paragraph2">
            content 2
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="paragraph3">
            content 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow-toggle.collapsed .icon-arrow-down
{
  display: none;
}

.arrow-toggle .icon-arrow-down
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.arrow-toggle.collapsed .icon-arrow-up
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.arrow-toggle .icon-arrow-up
{
  display: none;
}
```